# Label display based on cluster size

Tags: qgis, clustering, qgis-3, labeling

In QGIS 3.0, I am using the new clustering style.

[image]

I want to display labels based on cluster size.

What I tried in expression field:

```
 case
 when @cluster_size>5 then  "label_name" 
 end
```

[image]

Comment: I doubt it can work: the cluster regroup several points together, but you ask to label using a column, so a value from each individual feature. If it can be done at all, you would need to aggregate/summarize the column values to a single one

Comment: @JGH All ponctual markers of each cluster have distance of 0. For example, in my data, I have 163 markers for "Nantes" place. So I expect 163 "Nantes "labels overlapping.

Comment: Sometimes an if() expression works better than a case-when statement. I have no idea if it will help here, but it won't take long to try: if(@cluster_size>5, "label_name", null).

Comment: @csk Thank you for helping. Unfortunately not working...(no labels displayed)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The variables `@cluster_color` and `@cluster_size` only exist in the context of the cluster renderer. They cannot be used in expressions for labeling. To label point clusters based on these variables, we can use a font marker as part of the cluster symbol.

---

Change the Cluster symbol in layer style panel: 
[image]

Add a new symbol layer, symbol layer type: font marker (1)

Add an offset so the font marker appears to the side of the marker instead of directly on top of it (2)

Use data-defined settings to control the text of the font marker (3)

[image]

Use an expression like

> if(@cluster_size>5, "label_name", '')

[image]

**The third parameter in the above expression is two single quotation marks**, not one double quotation mark. This represents an empty string, resulting in no label being displayed when the "label_name" field has a null value.

I originally used the expression `if(@cluster_size>5, "label_name", null)`. 
With this expression, a default text label (A) will be displayed when the field value is null.