# Grouped "labels" for QGIS 3.0 Point Cluster styling?

Tags: qgis, style, clustering

I'm trying to make a cluster visualization of a vector point layer about trees with a few requirements:

- The clusters need to change depending on zoom level (solved)
- The clusters need to indicate how many vector objects are clustered (solved)
- The clusters need to have labels that describe the objects that are clustered
- This needs to be done with styling, so that the CRS can be copypasted (the data table will be updated and the clustering needs to be automatic)

I would like to show something like this in the final product (I inserted the black text by hand in MS Paint for reference):

[image]

The data for the trees:

[image]

The Point Cluster is only a visualization, so automatic labeling will create labels to individual objects, not to each cluster. Also, the @cluster-functions are only available inside the Cluster Point styling context. This is why I would like to make another layer with Cluster Points styling, which has a Font Marker as the cluster symbol. The text for the symbol would need to have conditional formatting. I would do it in SQL with something like this:

```
select count(*), "type" 
from @cluster
group by "type";
```

Which would yield something like this:

[image]

This would show the text in the way I need it on each different zoom level. However, I can't find a way to get a grip of the objects inside each cluster. The @cluster does not actually work.

How do I make grouped text clusters with Cluster Point styling, and how do I get a hold of the objects inside clusters?

Comment: If QGIS doesn't have this functionality, it would be a great [feature to request](https://issues.qgis.org).

Comment: If you haven't already, check out [this question}(https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/282417/label-display-based-on-cluster-size/282608#282608). In that case I found a workaround, but the fundamental issue is that the cluster renderer only has two expression variables: `@cluster_size` and `@cluster_color`. I don't know any way to label features based on whether they're in a cluster. But maybe someone else will think of a creative workaround.